# MongoDB sharding concept

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm trying to figure out the mechanism of MongoDB's sharding.
Can someone tell me if I got this thing right ?

Here is shards example of what I figured out:

**Sharded Cluster 1 :**

Shard1 - contains chunk1, chunk2 and chunk5 (Replica Set of primary and two secondaries, so we have backup for those chunks)

Shard2 - contains chunk3, chunk4 and chunk6 (MongoDB single instance, so we do not have any back up for those chunks)

**Sharded Cluster 2:**

Shard1 - contains chunk2, chunk3 and chunk6 (MongoDB single instance, so we do not have any back up for those chunks)

Shard2 - contains chunk1, chunk4 and chunk5 (Replica Set of primary and two secondaries, so we have backup for those chunks)

Comment: Have you looked at the output of 'sh.status()' in the shell?  It answers these types of questions directly.  If you have a hard time deciphering the output post it and we can annotate it.

Comment: I'm not trying to do it. Just to figure out the concept

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: did I get the idea right ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing such a wonderful information. Also I would like to add that sharding is basically done to increase I/O bandwidth and partition in-memory data for more proficient usage of distributed caching. Do [click here](http://www.nuodb.com/techblog/2013/05/22/nuodb-modern-alternative-to-database-sharding/) for more information regarding modern alternative to database sharding.